# GitHub Action filter and combine tag

Tags: docker, github-actions, schema.yml

I want to achieve GitHub action only run with specific tag commit check.

Here is my current yml

```
name: Docker Image CI

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - 'master'
    tags:
      - 'v*'

jobs:
  push_to_registry:
    name: Push Docker image to Docker Hub
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Check out the repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Log in to Docker Hub
        uses: docker/login-action@f054a8b539a109f9f41c372932f1ae047eff08c9
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_TOKEN }}
      - name: Extract metadata (tags, labels) for Docker
        id: meta
        uses: docker/metadata-action@98669ae865ea3cffbcbaa878cf57c20bbf1c6c38
        with:
          images: xx/xx
      - name: Build and push Docker image
        uses: docker/build-push-action@ad44023a93711e3deb337508980b4b5e9bcdc5dc
        with:
          context: ./aspnet-core/
          file: ./aspnet-core/Dockerfile
          push: true
          tags: server.${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}
          labels: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.labels }}
```

But, the action run with every master commit, and I want to update the tags with something like `server.${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}`, it will throw error. If I only use `${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}`, the error is gone.

But, I want to achieve auto tag the docker image like `server.v1.0.1` which `server` is hardcode and `v1.0.1` is from commit tag.

Comment: Your `on:` trigger means it runs on either `tags` or `master`. If you want it to only run when pushing a tag, just remove the `branches` part. Also note that a tag is not pushed "to a branch".

Comment: Please also review my answer on using versions of an action: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70192880/how-to-know-what-version-of-a-github-action-to-use/70196496#70196496

Comment: Edward: Did you try using `'server.${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}'` with the `'` for the action `tags` inputs?

Comment: @GuiFalourd it did not work.

Comment: What is the error that you get?