# Bad Identation on a Map Entry in GitHub Actions

Tags: java, github-actions, workflow

I tried to create my first workflow and I have doubts about how to fix it

```
  name: Setup Java JDK
  uses: actions/setup-java@v1.3.0
  with:
    # The Java version to make available on the path. Takes a whole or semver Java version, or 1.x syntax (e.g. 1.8 => Java 8.x)
    java-version: '1.8'
    # The package type (jre, jdk, jdk+fx)
    java-package: jdk
    # The architecture (x86, x64) of the package.
    architecture: # optional, default is x64
    # Path to where the compressed JDK is located. The path could be in your source repository or a local path on the agent.
    jdkFile: # optional
    # ID of the distributionManagement repository in the pom.xml file. Default is `github`
    server-id: # optional
    # Environment variable name for the username for authentication to the Apache Maven repository. Default is $GITHUB_ACTOR
    server-username: # optional
    # Environment variable name for password or token for authentication to the Apache Maven repository. Default is $GITHUB_TOKEN
    server-password: # optional
    # Path to where the settings.xml file will be written. Default is ~/.m2.
    settings-path: # optional
```

They show me a error of a bad indentation on a map entry in `actions/setup-java`

Comment: Please create a [minimal reproducer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The snippet you showed looks (syntactically) okay.

Comment: Also note that `acitons-setup-java` is available as `v3` and better use major tags [unless you need a very specific  version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70196496/1080523).